# Is locally completeness a topological property?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I know that *completeness* itself is [not a topological property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1565350/415941) because a complete and a not complete metric space can be homeomorphic, e.g. $\Bbb R$ and $(0,1)$.

However, both $\Bbb R$ and $(0,1)$ are *locally complete* (each point has a neighborhood that is complete under the induced metric). As all examples I know of are of this form, the naturally occuring next question is

> **Question:** Is being locally complete a *topological property*?

Or the other way around: are there metric spaces which are homeomorphic, but one is locally complete and the other one is not?

Comment: What is a complete topological space?

Comment: @Thompson That terminology is not used in the question.

Comment: my mistake. Apologies.

Comment: This result https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21954/locally-complete-space-is-topologically-equivalent-to-a-complete-space is a partial answer (the first hit when I googled "locally complete space")

Comment: @Thompson I know of this question. As far as I can tell it does not answer my question, it just says if there is a locally complete metric, then there is a complete one. Maybe I am missing how it can help here. Please explain. I understand this post, so one can refer to it in an answer.

Comment: I see. I'm making a big mess of this so I think I'll bow out of trying to add anything useful!

Comment: How is $(0,1)$ locally complete?

Comment: @ngenisis Any $x\in(0,1)$ has a small closed interval $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]\subset(0,1)$. This interval is complete.

Comment: Ah, I'm accustomed to neighborhoods being open by definition.

Comment: @ngenisis Oh. I learned that a neighborhood just *contains* an open set that contains the point.

Comment: @M.Winter And you've learnt well.

Comment: @Thompson: maybe the idea in the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071275/quasi-cauchy-sequences-in-general-topology could be used to define a "complete topological space"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The irrational numbers are not locally complete, but they are homeomorphic to the [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$, which can be given a metric turning it into a complete metric space.

(For example, endow $\mathbb N$ with the discrete metric and set $d(s, t) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i}d(s_i,t_i)$).

Comment: +1. And for the OP, thinking about this counterexample can lead to considering local *compactness*, which is of course a topological property (and one which Baire space lacks).

Comment: I would be glad if you can show the "obvious" homeomorphism between the irrationals and $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ (with what topology?). I am a bit confused whether the example below should show me the complete or incomplete metric.

Comment: It's not obvious (I never used that word), just well known.  Essentially, you map an irrational number to the coefficients in its continued fraction representation.  See the Wikipedia article I linked to for details.

Comment: The topology on $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ is the product topology.  Equivalently, it is the topology induced by the metric I provided, which makes the space into a complete metric space.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of proving that the irrationals can be made complete with respect to a metric $d$ which is equivalent to the usual one consists in providing such a metric. This can be donne as follows: let $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an enumeration of the rationals. Then, if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb Q$, define$$d(x,y)=|x-y|+\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}\inf\left(1,\left|\max_{i\leqslant k}\frac1{|x-q_i|}-\max_{i\leqslant k}\frac1{|y-q_i|}\right|\right).$$